# GeoIP is not working for me?

Tags: geolocation, geo, geoip, geotargetting

I am trying to work with geoip to display different ads to different locations.
I am trying to display this code but nothing comes up:

```
<?php

$IP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

include("geoip.inc");

$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);

$CountryCode = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $IP);
geoip_close($gi);

// ****DO NOT TOUCH ABOVE THIS LINE.******
//***Consult the Readme if you aren't sure what you're doing****

if ($CountryCode=="US"){

    echo 'USA';
} else {
    echo 'INTERNATIONAL OFFERS GO HERE';
}

?>
```

This as well, doesn't bring anything:

```
<?php
$country_name = apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME");
print "Country: " . $country_name;
?>
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_ADDR'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_REGION'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_REGION_NAME'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_CITY'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_DMA_CODE'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_AREA_CODE'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_LATITUDE'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_LONGITUDE'];
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE'];
?>
```

geoip says it is installed on my ubuntu. GeoIP.dat is sitting in the root folder.
Can you help me and tell me what to do, so maybe I get to the bottom of this problem..?
A step by step guidance can be really helpful here since I don't manage to get it working.

Many thanks!

Comment: give us the ouput of "nginx -V"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$gi = geoip_open( "GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
```